# Where is the man page for "pthread_mutexattr_getrobust"?

Tags: manpage

I can't find the manual page for `pthread_mutexattr_getrobust`.

Answer (score 1):

This function is known to be missing a manpage.

- [The kernel documentation's list of missing manpages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/missing_pages.html)
- [Launchpag bug #480649](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/480649)

For the moment, you'll have to use the specification, or the GNU online documentation:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.html